# How to create a user in ubuntu for ftp, and lock the account to a specific ftp folder

Tags: ubuntu, security, ftp

I want to create a ftp user on my ubuntu server, and lock the user to a specific folder to read/write to.

I read I use the /usr/sbin/useradd but I don't see how I set the password?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/10/ubuntu-9-10-chroot-jail-for-ftp/) explains how you can lock a user in a chroot jail with [`vsftpd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vsftpd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).  The key option is:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

This means the user can not leave their home directory.  There are multiple ways to create a user.  By default, `adduser` will prompt you for a password and directory info.

However, you should consider [sftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol), with openssh-server, instead.  There are ways to secure FTP, e.g. tunneling it over SSH or SSL.  However, SFTP was originally designed with security in mind.

Comment: Worth noting that OpenSSH only supports chrooting from v4.8p1 onwards. I'm not sure which version of OpenSSH Ubuntu ships with, but I know that CentOS 5.* comes with 4.7 so it may not be available. It's still possible to achieve, but judging by the question the OP will likely struggle.